# as much as I want to believe you

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

> ... but I haven't seen any proofs yet. So as much as I want to believe you, I just can't right now.

Is this phrased correctly and naturally? Would it be more natural to omit the second *as*?

Comment: The second 'as' is natural and should be included. In this context 'proof' is usually an uncountable noun used in the singular: "I haven't seen any proof". Used in the plural, proofs are what a printer or film lab might give you as an example to show what will be printed, before committing to production.

Comment: ...but the first 'as' could be omitted. _So, much as I want to believe you..._

Comment: Mathematicians discuss proofs that are countable.